# how to make a button do two actions - elevate up and when pressed the second time go down?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

Is their a new way to write this code... Anyway, I need the user to press the button to first go down and then go up the down measurements are 229 for y and 160 for x... how is this done?

```
- (IBAction)closeHints:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
CGPoint center = [hints center];
center.x = 160;
center.y = 290;
[hints setCenter:center];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIView` and seek out the methods for block-based animation.

Comment: You need to keep a bool variable that you can use to know whether you need to go up or down - test its value, animate as required and then flip the bool, so if it was YES, set it to NO and vice-versa

Comment: @rmaddy Yes Sir, Will do Right away!

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll try that after I read the Methods for block-base animation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)closeHints:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         CGPoint center = [hints center];
                         if(hints.center.y != 290){
                              center.y = 290;
                         }
                         else{
                              center.y = originY; //you should define it
                         }
                         [hints setCenter:center];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

}
```